# Cannot edit my navigation menu

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n

I cannot edit my navigation menu.  I think this comes from upgrading from Drupal 6 to 7.

I get this error message:

> URL:
>   http://www.energyjustice.net/admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation
>
> Referrer: http://www.energyjustice.net/admin/structure/menu
>
> Message:
>
> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 3 passed to l() must be an array,
>   boolean given, called in
>   /home/energy/public_html/modules/menu/menu.admin.inc on line 102 and
>   defined in l() (line 2340 of
>   /home/energy/public_html/includes/common.inc).

I've googled this problem and it happens a lot - I just haven't found a solution that I can use.  What can I do?

It might have something to do with the internationalization/translation and that I had an & symbol in the menu name.  I've since changed the name, but the problem remains.

Rebuilding the menu doesn't help.

Drupal 7.14.

Comment: It looks like this is the problem: http://drupal.org/node/328110 and Drupal was patched to fix it.  I just don't want to remove all my 100+ menu items and manually recreate it.

Comment: I ended up manually recreating the menu.  I think there might be a way to avoid doing this by fixing the menu_links table, possibly the BLOB "options" field that is a serialized array.  However I couldn't figure it out.